# Como mostrar los valores en cada barra de un chart

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buenos Dias,Quisiera si me pueden ayudar estoy realizando un grafico estadistico con chart en asp.net c# por lo cual ya me salio el grafico pero lo que no me sale es que quiero que en cada barra aparesca el numero real que tiene por ejemplo asi como la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualmente me sale pero sin esos numeros de arriba y eso es lo que quisiera**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualmente este es mi codigo en html .**

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Width="600px">
                        <Titles>
                            <asp:Title Text="Costo Mensual"></asp:Title>
                        </Titles>
                        <Series>
                            <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="0" YValueMembers="2">
                            </asp:Series>
                        </Series>
                        <ChartAreas>
                            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                            </asp:ChartArea>
                        </ChartAreas>
                    </asp:Chart>
```

**y en el codigo :**

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ObtenerCadenaConexion());
                cn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("GenerarBarraLineal", cn);
                cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@opt", SqlDbType.Int);
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@anio", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@suministro", SqlDbType.VarChar);

                cmd2.Parameters["@opt"].Value = 1;
                cmd2.Parameters["@anio"].Value = cboPeriodo.SelectedItem.Text;
                cmd2.Parameters["@suministro"].Value = "";

                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
                da.Fill(ds);
                Chart1.DataSource = ds;
                cn.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que estas buscando esto:

```
IsValueShownAsLabel="true"
```

dentro del tag series, con lo cual te quedaria asi:

```
<asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="0" YValueMembers="2" IsValueShownAsLabel="true">
```

Comment: Excelente @gbianchi sabes algun documento para aprender mas seria muy util mi hermano o una consulta si se podra mostrar cuando paso el mouse , excelente mi hermano